# If I have a circumference and a rectangle inscribed into it, is the diagonal of the rectangle equal to the diameter of the circumference?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, proof-explanation

I know that, indirectly, I have considered that (what I typed on the title) and, it might be true, but I want to prove it. I have done this so far: Let´s suppose I have a circumference and four points in it, $A,B,C,D$, and because it is rectangle, (I thought I could say that because if I calculate both slopes I get to $m_2m_1=-1$) I made this consideration , and its to give the cordinates to those points: $$A(x_1, y_1) , B(x_2, y_1) , C(x_1, y_2) , D(x_2, y_2)$$

And that all made this figure:
[image]

I hope you get what I mean, because probably I am being redudant, anyway, thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless an author gives an idiosyncratic definition, saying that a polygon is *inscribed* in a circle means that all of its edges are chords of the circle, just as your picture illustrates.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.   Euclid Book III Proposition 31 says that an angle inscribed in a semicircle is a right angle, and that if chords of a circle meet on the boundary at a right angle then that angle is inscribed in a semicircle.

http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookIII/propIII31.html

Comment: Thanks @Ethan Bolker, though I got a bit confused with your comment =).

Comment: please the exact reference!!!. I have asked my teacher something about this topic and I think He gave me the  answer. And it´s that if you have chords, and you take the middlepoint a the chords and draw a perpendicular from each of them, the point where those perpendicular intersect is the centre of the circumference.

Comment: And that can be demonstrated, in fact, I think, it´s a property of rectangles. But then I was asking to myself, if those perpendiculars could intersect, and the intersection wouldn´t be the centre of the circumference. I know that you can prove, that stuff of the perpendiculars, but how could I prove that the intersection of the chords is the centre of the circumference, or could they intersect in a point that isn´t the centre of the circumference?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have the proof nearly written. You write that $P$ is at an equal distance from $A, B, C$, and even $D$ ? How many points sharing this property with $P$ exist...?

Comment: I don´t understand your comment =(.

Comment: Another hint then: how many circles can pass through three points?

Comment: I´d say one, but I don´t know why =(.